# MVC3 - large DB, large set of controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, structure

I am trying to figure out of there is a way to arrange this differently.

- I have six databases.

  They each have at least a dozen tables.

Some of the tables are simple with only a few fields, the most one has is 11 (which is for logging). In `aspnet mvc3` I have a model per table. I also have a controller per model. I have a lot of controllers. They are organized in `hierarchical folders`. I like the separation of where views are, and where controllers are so I would prefer not to use `Areas`. The url's are very clean, and I do not need to change any of the routing. Using `multiple projects` under one solution umbrella feels like overkill.

Does anyone use a different approach to structuring their controllers other than I am using or have covered here?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How are you trying to organize the controllers differently? Can you give an example of how you're doing it now? Also, `Areas` sound like a perfect way to achieve separation while maintaining the hierarchical structure to me.

Comment: @shuniar - I am using hierarchical folders to organize the controllers at the moment. The folders are broken out into functionality groups. It is easy to navigate to the correct controller, but when I begin working on 3 or more controllers at once the vs10 solution explorer scrolling begins to add up. There are easily 50+ controllers so they have to be grouped in some fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50+ controllers sounds like you probably need a bit of a redesign.

Controllers should group together common functionality, you don't necessarily need one per table/model - especially if you have 50+ models!

For example, if several tables/models are related to logging, create a LoggingController, and put the individual controller actions you have already created into this.

Also, have a look for any controllers with only a couple of actions - this may be an indication that they could be put into another controller.

Alternatively, MVC doesn't really care where you keep your controllers, so split them up into folders under the Controllers folder - you will only run into issues if you have two controllers with the same name in different namespaces.